# SVG graphics + iPad3

Tags: ipad, svg, size, scale, graphic

On a desktop, I can get this button to display nicely (in Firefox anyway, I only need it to work on very few browsers) and it scales appropriately.

http://www.coflash.com/svg/

However, on an iPad3, the icon changes size and seems to be cut off. I can't figure out why this is happening. I'm guessing it's because of the pixel density/higher DPI but I don't even know where to begin on getting around it.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Hmmm, seems to do the same thing on an iPad 2 as well :/

Comment: On an unrelated note: You know that you can reference shapes in SVG and thus re-use them?